# PHP session_start() causes script to run indefinitely

Tags: php, apache, session

I haven't had this problem on any other server, so I'm wondering if anyone else experienced this issue. The strange part is that the lock up happens at random - sessions will work fine for 10 minutes to an hour, then I'll make a request and I'll just see the browser waiting for reply. It never times out and I have to restart Apache2 to get sessions running.

My test.php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo 'got here';
```

When I get a lock up, commenting out the session_start(); shows 'got here'. So it's something to do with PHP sessions. It's setup to use files in /var/lib/php/session. Opening an incognito window doesn't help.

Potentially relevant details:

Web Server: Apache2 with Prefork

OS: CentOS 6.4 x64

HD: 5+ GB free

Memory: 10+ GB free

If you need any other info please ask!

Comment: You can use `fuser` comman to identify the process that is locking the session file.

Comment: Can you provide your Apache and PHP configurations? Also, Apache and PHP rpm versions? This has nothing to do with Google Compute Engine, as GCE is only an IaaS and it doesn't impact the Apache+PHP software stack.